# How to JOIN 2 tables on mySql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two tables: **publick_feed** and **users**

I want to SELECT all from **public_feed** and also SELECT a three columns from **users** whose **id** is the same of **user_id** in **public_feed**
and assign the rows returned from **public_feed** to the column in users table ( correspondent)

I try this:

```
<?php

$sql = "
SELECT * FROM public_feed
WHERE user_id IN
(SELECT id FROM users) AND 
(SELECT Firstname,Lastname,Avatar FROM users WHERE id IN(SELECT user_id FROM public_feed))  

";

$query  = mysqli_query($dbc_conn,$sql);
if(mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0){
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
        //echo rows with correspondent details from the users table
        echo $row['user_id'];
        }
}

<?
```

Please any help will be much appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Show us the expected result as well!

Comment: I want to return all rows from T1 and return the 3 columns from T2 once the id column in T2 is equivalent in user_id column in T1

Comment: Please, try not to use capital letters in columns name. some storing engines are case sensitive, some of them are not. If You want to save your time of debugging, use column names like `first_name` or `firstname`

Comment: Explicit explanation !. Thanks to stackoverflow for giving us such a powerful platform to learn. Am  grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or version with left join in case if there is no user in public_feed, and you still want to fetch user data

```
SELECT
  u.*, f.* 
FROM
  public_feed f LEFT JOIN
  users u ON f.user_id = u.id;
```

Because author asked for explanation, here it is:

First we are going to use table name alias to make query shorter

```
public_feed f
```

and

```
users u
```

we are saying that want to refer to tables with an alias. Of course `*` means that we want to select all columns

```
SELECT users.*, public_feed.*
```

is equal to

```
SELECT u.*, f.*
```

Of course you can use any other letters as an alias

Next we are saying that public_feed.user_id must be equal to users.id. But when public feed entry does not exists just display columns with null values. This is why we are using LEFT JOIN instead of INNER JOIN. In general JOINS are used to fetch related data from more than one related tables.

`ON` keyword is saying values from which columns in the tables must be equal to satisfy the request

Comment: wow!!...your sql looks great and it worked for me just exactly how I want it.

Comment: Please I want get the understanding of your solution....please can you explain  to me..??

Comment: I'm glad that it was helpful for you :)

Comment: I can see u create a custom letter u and f... why did u create that? I can also see you're using a LEFT JOIN keyword  and ON keyword.. what is that doing?

Comment: I'm editing my answer, so I will try to include answers to all your questions

Comment: Please read the mysql documentation as well: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html

Answer (score 2):

I think doing a join would be cleaner than using a complicated subquery:

```
SELECT u.Firstname,
       u.Lastname,
       u.Avatar,
       COALESCE(pf.User_id, 'NA'),
       COALESCE(pf.Post, 'NA'),
       COALESCE(pf.Date, 'NA')
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN public_feed pf
    ON u.Id = pf.User_id
```

I chose a `LEFT JOIN` of `users` against `public_feed` on the assumption that every feed will have an entry in the users table, but not necessarily vice-versa.  For those users who have no feed entries, `NA` would appear in those columns and that user would appear in only a single record.

Comment: your solution only return details from users table...how do i return all rows from public_feed table and also return Firstname,Lastname,Avatar FROM users table once the id in users table matches the user_id in public_feed table ??

Comment: `your solution only return details from users table` ... no, it returns every feed record which matches to a user.  Do you have any feed records which have no user?  This would seem strange to me.

Comment: I the feed records have also a user or the owner of the feed....anyway thanks for your time and effort ...someone solved it for me. Thank you.

Comment: @jamesOduro I'm not convinced the answer you selected is what you actually want.  Are you sure you don't want users to appear even if they never blogged?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen , The answer I selected only returns rows public_feed and correspondent collumns from users table. Those users who are not in the public_feed table never show up upon testing the answer I selected.